# C# HttpClient POST request pass already encoded data

Tags: c#, http

I have already encoded data that wants to pass as is the String to HttpClient PostRequest

but FormUrlEncodedContent only accepts a dictonary as parameter

I want something like client.PostAsync(url, plain_string_content)

```
 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {

      try
                {

                     var response = client.PostAsync(url, content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                     string resp=response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                     return resp;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`HttpClient.SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post);
request.Content = new StringContent(plain_string_content);
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Note that, after all, `PostAsync` and other `HttpClient`'s methods are shortcuts of `SendAsync`.